# ASP.NET no funciona jquery en mi button

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Tengo un botón el cual quiero que realice un preventdefault, la función click asociada a ese botón no me funciona, para probar dispongo de lo siguiente:

```
<script src="../js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnGuardar').click(function () {
        alert("Es una prueba");
    });
});

</script>
```

y el boton

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGuardar" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Resulta lo siguiente, si cambio '#btnGuardar' por el elemento "a" FUNCIONA para lo que sería enlaces, entonces como puede ser que simplemente cambiando la a por mi botón no funcione?  y creo que la cuestión puede venir porque mi webform esta asociado a un masterpage, ya que creando un webform independiente probé el código para el botón y me funciona.

Comment: este es tu boton asp `<asp:Button ID="btnGuardar" runat="server" Text="Button" />` pero html que genera, quiza por ahi este el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder seleccionar un boton de asp.net en query deberias utilizar

```
$('#<%=btnGuardar.ClientID%>').click(function () {
```

o sino

```
$("[id*='btnGuardar']").click(function () {
```

este ultimo busca los controles por id pero valida si contiene el nombre de forma aproximada.

[Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Recuerda que asp.net cambia los id cuando renderiza el control, es mas inspecciona el html generado usando el Developer tools (al cual accedes con F12) y veras el id que realmente tiene asignado el boton

Comment: te agradezco leandro!! funciona!! y te hago otra pregunta.. como hago para que se ejecute mi OnClick="btnGuardar_Click"  ? ya que en la script agregue un preventDefault puesto que es una validacion